# Having issue every time I open android studio. Getting error: Gradle 'MyExpenses2' project refresh failed. What should I do?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, application-error, system-error

[image of error i am getting everytime android studio is started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNEyY.png)
Every time i open android studio i get the following error: Gradle 'MyExpenses2' project refresh failed Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

I am not able to proceed with my project. What should I do?

I tried many different solutions like invalidating cache, installing different sdk tools and updating sdk tools but nothing works.
I dont even know why i am getting this error.

Comment: May be close the project and open a different project? The project has nothing to do with starting Android Studio. The first thing I do on a new Android Studio installation is deactivating the setting `Reopen projects on startup`.

Comment: Tried starting another project. Still same problem. What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: What is the output in your gradle console? It could provide with more information. Generally, errors relating gradle occur because your project is not compatible with your android studio´s gradle, or the gradle JDK. Also, if you are connected to an unstable network, you could try toggling hte offline mode.

Comment: I assume this is because you are using a heavily outdated Android Studio version that does not work together with your Android SDK version or has other prkblems.. Delete it and the Android SDK installation and also delete all Android Studio related folders from your appdata folder (hidden folder in your user data folder). Then download latest Android Studio version and start with a fresh copy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.